# The LNP won the election, but lost my district. Do they still follow through on what my local representative said they'd do if they won?

Tags: voting, australia

The LNP won the election, but lost my district.

The promises that my LNP representative made, are they still going to happen, even though he lost?

Comment: Promises of politicians are usually not enforceable, are they? They may or may not do it. The future will tell.

Answer (score 3):

The Liberal coalition party won the election in Australia and so they will be able to form the federal government. That coalition will be able to set the legislative programme, and the Labor and other parties will be in opposition.

So in terms of the promises made by the LNP, insofar as these are national policies, then yes, the LNP will be able to make national policy that affects Queensland and your local region.  So, for example, the LNP has promised to provide better transport infrastructure through major road upgrades.  This is a promise that the LNP can now attempt to deliver on.

On the other hand, there may be personal promises that the candidate has made, which are not part of national policy. For example, a candidate might promise to put pressure on the government not to close a local hospital. As this would have been a personal promise, not part of the party promise, the defeated candidate cannot deliver on that promise.

Similarly, the Labor party might have won your district. The personal promises made by the Labor candidate can now be delivered (though as an opposition MP, actually getting anything done is more difficult). But the national policies of the Labor party have been defeated, and the Labor party will now have to spend more time in opposition.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer posted here is good, but there is perhaps another factor that can influence things, and that is State Governments. I don't want to presume this is what will happen in your area, but I'm adding this post as a way to offer some additional value around the mechanics of "promises"

States are responsible for service delivery (Health, Education, Roads etc.) so when a federal government promises something that relates to state-delivered services, it is given to the state to implement. Many of these are also co-funded on an 80/20 split (e.g.80% fed, 20% state, such as the Linkfield Rd overpass to use another QLD example).

If the State and Fed groups are not on the same side of the political fence, sometimes this can lead to foot-dragging on one side or the other; or both sides claiming delivery of the promise. ;-)

If the promises were funding for initiatives, or grants for local bodies, your mileage may vary. Sometimes, advocacy to the local state of fed member will offer an avenue for the grant/initiative to be delivered, even though one side or another originally committed to it.

In the end, if the promise was a worthy one, perhaps book in and have a chat with your local member (regardless of whether they are red/blue and see whether a little local advocacy can help get it across the line).